# bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/ColorPropType.js`

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-native-ios, shoutem

I have this error after I installed shoutem ui to my project and imported to my ui. "bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/ColorPropType.js"

I've tried to follow the suggestion from the react-native error page

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.

   2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
   3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
   4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

Answer (score 1):

Some things broke with versions >= 0.58.x.
use below process or using react-native <0.58

create a script file 
fix.sh

```
cp ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/DeprecatedPropTypes/DeprecatedViewStylePropTypes.js ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes.js
cp ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/DeprecatedPropTypes/DeprecatedColorPropType.js ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/ColorPropType.js
cp ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/DeprecatedPropTypes/DeprecatedImageStylePropTypes.js ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/ImageStylePropTypes.js
```

and in package.json

```
  {
"scripts": {
"postinstall": "sh ./fix.sh"
 },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shoutem/ui": "^0.23.12",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5"
  }
 }
```